# python ndarray : how do you combine the list picking only certain data

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Updated: 
CSV File Contents:

```
iterations,fitness,time,fevals
0,498.0,0.003076461,11
10,500.0,0.004095651,21
```

I read a csv file using np.genfromtxt with this syntax

```
a = np.genfromtxt (fname1, delimiter=",",dtype=float,names=True)
b = np.genfromtxt (fname2, delimiter=",",dtype=float,names=True)
```

When I checked the datatype, it reported that it is as a

```
'numpy.ndarray'>
'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The shape that is reported was :

```
(2,)
(2,)
```

1. Since the resulting contents is suppose to be a 2D array, how can I convert the files a, b so that  I can join the two  using the first column as  a join key and then apply some mean function on the 1, 2 column only

Comment: `np.mean([a[1,2],b[1,2]])`

Comment: @ThomasGuenet, Im getting this error     upd_csv = np.mean([a[1,2],b[1,2]])
IndexError: too many indices for array
a.shape = (301,)
b.shape (301,)

Comment: Certainly be cause you should have written: `a = np.array([(    0.,  498.,  0.00507646,    11.), (   10.,  500.,  0.00509565,    21.)])` and  you do not have 301 numbers in `b` but only 2*4

Comment: @ThomasGuenet, a and b are coming out as a ndarray with dimension of (2, ) and not (2,4).. so it seems that it is appearing as a series of tuples.. is there a faster way to convert it to a 2d array of (2,4) ?

Comment: The code in your question is misleading : I thought it was assignments, but I now understand that `a` and `b` are results. So a and b are objects of two tuples containing 4 reals. But are a and b numpy arrays or just list ?

Comment: and and b are both numpy arrays with shape of (2,)

Comment: With this definition : `a = np.array([(    0.,  498.,  0.00507646,    11.), (   10.,  500.,  0.00509565,    21.)])`, the result of `np.shape(a)` is `(2L, 4L)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used the option `names` of `genfromtxt`, python created a special kind of array : `a` and `b` are of the followind kind:

```
array([(0.0, 498.0, 0.003076461, 11.0), (10.0, 500.0, 0.004095651, 21.0)],
      dtype=[('iterations', '<f8'), ('fitness', '<f8'), ('time', '<f8'), ('fevals', '<f8')])
```

So to mean the value just do :

```
np.mean([a[1][2],b[1][2]])
```

If you want the ordinary array type get ride of `names` option and use `skiprows` instead (or `skip_header` starting from numpy-1.10).

```
a=np.genfromtxt('a.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=float,skiprows=1)
b=np.genfromtxt('b.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=float,skiprows=1)
print np.mean([a[1,2],b[1,2]])
```

`a` is now an ordinary `numpy.array` object:

```
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   4.98000000e+02,   3.07646100e-03,
          1.10000000e+01],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   5.00000000e+02,   4.09565100e-03,
          2.10000000e+01]])
```